# ASP.NET MVC Core ViewModel post back including IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to somehow not clear a file input when posting back a viewmodel in ASP.NET MVC Core? I know the IFormFile doesn't include a member that designates the directory of the file selected.

So, if the view model gets sent back in the situation that ModelState is invalid the file input is cleared. Is it possible to avoid this without resorting entirely to clientside validation?

Here's an example controller and template to more adequately explain what I am saying

**Controller:**

```
namespace Example
{
    public class CreateVm
    {
        public IFormFile aFile{ get; set; }
        public string someText{get; set;}
    }

    public class ExampleController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Action()
        {
            var vm = new CreateVm();
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(CreateVm vm)
        {
            // Something invalidates the model state
            // The supplied viewmodel isn't valid, send it back
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View(vm);

            // Do stuff here
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Create));
        }
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
@model Example.CreateVm
<form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input asp-for="someText"/>
    <input asp-for="aFile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

From what I understand it is not possible to get the file directory in javascript so I don't think that's a viable way to go about it either.

Comment: No. This is not possible. Your server code cannot access a file in users computer (re selecting the file). If you absolutely want this behavior, you may do an ajax upload and have the file temporarily stored in the server and send a unique id of the file to the client(browser) and when the form gets submitted, send this unique id to server as part of form data and let the server find the file using this unique id (from the server) and use it.

Comment: Alright, thanks.
I spent a lot of time googling and basically got to a similar conclusion myself, but I wanted to be entirely sure before abandoning it completely.